# SGI STL map traversal

Tags: c++, stl, red-black-tree

I stumbled upon SGI's STL map [implementation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html) (stl_map.h), and there it has this piece of code for finding an item:

```
template <class _Key, class _Value, class _KeyOfValue, 
          class _Compare, class _Alloc>
typename _Rb_tree<_Key,_Value,_KeyOfValue,_Compare,_Alloc>::iterator 
_Rb_tree<_Key,_Value,_KeyOfValue,_Compare,_Alloc>::find(const _Key& __k)
{
  _Link_type __y = _M_header;      // Last node which is not less than __k. 
  _Link_type __x = _M_root();      // Current node. 

  while (__x != 0) 
    if (!_M_key_compare(_S_key(__x), __k))
      __y = __x, __x = _S_left(__x);
    else
      __x = _S_right(__x);

  iterator __j = iterator(__y);   
  return (__j == end() || _M_key_compare(__k, _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? 
     end() : __j;
}
```

I must be reading it wrong but it seems to me that it always traverses the whole tree. Why doesn't it stop as soon as it finds the wanted key? Could someone please explain to me how it works?

I would have expected that in case of red-black tree one first finds out whether an item's key is the same as the searched-for key, and if not then one steps either to left or right. The above code doesn't seem to perform the first check.

Edit: For example, I would like to find the key "4" in the following tree:

```
         4
       /   \
     2       6
    / \     / \
   1   3   5   7
```

1. x is 4
2. !compare goes to left (4 < 4), x is 2, y is 4)
3. !compare goes to right (2 < 4), x is 3
4. !compare goes to left (3 < 4), x is NULL
5. terminate

I thought that the NULLs are only at the leafs..?

Comment: "the same" costs two comparisons, because the comparator only tells you if `a < b`.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, of course. But why does it stop at the leafs only?

Comment: Not only at the leaves - at any node with zero or one child (where that one edge leads in the "wrong" direction).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik see the edit: I thought RB trees always have two children in the interior nodes..?

Comment: That's not a valid binary search tree.

Comment: @T.C. Right you are! See the edit... Now I see how it finds the correct key but I still don't understand why it traverses the whole tree and does not terminate as early as possible? Because, **on average**, it is more faster to save that one compare, as opposite to be able to terminate early?

Comment: a) Obviously a tree containing two elements can't possibly have all nodes with either zero or two children. b) As @T.C. notes, that example of yours makes no sense. c) Why does it matter that the search always goes down to the leaves? The tree depth is `O(log n)`, so the complexity requirements are satisfied.

Comment: Yes, on average it's faster to save one compare than to terminate early. There are more leaf nodes than there are interior nodes, and  more generally, there are many more nodes close to the leaves than there are close to the root. The probability of being able to terminate early enough to amortize all those extra comparisons is low.